# Isn't there another Atronach Forge?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

UESP's article on the [Atronach Forge](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Atronach_Forge) seems to imply that there's only one, in [The Midden](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Midden) at the [College of Winterhold](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:College_of_Winterhold_%28place%29).  However, I seem to recall stumbling across another one during a quest at some point.  I'm having a hard time remembering when/where this was, so it's perfectly possible I'm mis-remembering.

Can someone tell me if I'm crazy, or if there is actually another Atronach Forge that's just not been documented on UESP?  Could it be not documented because it's not usable?

Comment: I have run across a few 'summoning circle' type things through out the lands of Skyrim.. They are not as complete and done up as that forge but it maybe be possible you are thinking of one of those.

Comment: @James Maybe point me in that direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one *functional* Atronach forge, underneath Winterhold.

I don't recall any reuse of the art assets for the forge elsewhere, but Skyrim is a big place, so it's certainly possible that the model is sitting around in another cave that I've forgotten about.